# How to get the built in File type icon used by Visual Studio programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working on a VSIX project which requires to display the selected file's (in Solution explorer), file type icon  in a Custom Tool-window. Could anyone please advise me on how to obtain the File type Icon used by Visual studio IDE programmatically?

e.g. Obtain following Image Icon (as highlighted) for PNG files
 [image]

`Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(*path*)` solution mentioned in many stackoverflow 
 threads doesn't work for me since it provides the Shell icons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supposed to use the [Visual Studio Image Service and Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/extensibility/image-service-and-catalog). However this document doesn't explain how to get the image for a given file.

You'll have to use the [IVsImageService2.GetImageMonikerForFile Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsimageservice2.getimagemonikerforfile?view=visualstudiosdk-2017). As described in the document, you can get GDI/Winforms, Win32 or WPF images. Here is a sample code that does it for WPF's BitmapSource:

```
public static async Task<BitmapSource> GetWpfImageForFileAsync(AsyncPackage package, string filename, int width, int height)
{
    if (package == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));

    var svc = (IVsImageService2)await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(SVsImageService));
    if (svc == null)
        return null;

    var mk = svc.GetImageMonikerForFile(filename);
    var atts = new ImageAttributes
    {
        StructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ImageAttributes)),
        Format = (uint)_UIDataFormat.DF_WPF,
        LogicalHeight = width,
        LogicalWidth = height,
        Flags = (uint)_ImageAttributesFlags.IAF_RequiredFlags,
        ImageType = (uint)_UIImageType.IT_Bitmap
    };

    var obj = svc.GetImage(mk, atts);
    if (obj == null)
        return null;

    obj.get_Data(out object data);
    return (BitmapSource)data;
}
```

Here is how you can use it for example at package initialization:

```
public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
{
    ThreadHelper.ThrowIfNotOnUIThread();

    // note a valid extension is sufficient
    _pngBitmap = await GetWpfImageForFileAsync(package, "whatever.png", 32, 32);

   // etc...
}
```